# What is the function to check network admin?

Tags: network-admin

I know there is a function to check normal admin area.

Its `is_admin()`

Is there any other function available to chevk network admin something like `is_network_admin()`  ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google search: http://hitchhackerguide.com/2011/02/24/is_network_admin/

```
is_network_admin();
```

:)